# Regular expression for 'b' not preceded by an odd number of 'a's

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write a regular expression for a pattern `b` not preceded by an odd number of repetitions of the letter `a` using Python's `re` module. In principle,

```
(?<=(?<!a)(aa)*)b
```

would do what I want, but this isn't legal because lookbehinds need to have a fixed length.

How can I do this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Python, apparently. Added the tag for clarity

Comment: You may use your pattern with Python PyPi `regex`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As I said, I am using Python's `re` module, where they aren't.

Comment: Since it is a positive lookbehind, you do not even need. Just use `((?<!a)(?:aa)*)b`. Since you capture all `a`s before `b`, you may decide what to do with the match further in the code, or with a backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: I changed the close reason link at the top to showcase this common approach.